# The name 'grdUserActivity' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have a grid that is named grdUserActivity.  I'm not sure what the error means.

The name 'grdUserActivity' does not exist in the current context

C#

```
public partial class frmViewPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Declares the DataSet
            dsUserActivity myDataSet = new dsUserActivity();

            // Fill the dataset with what is returned from the function
            myDataSet = clsDataLayer.GetUserActivity(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"));

            // Sets the DataGrid to the DataSource based on the table
            grdUserActivity.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["tblUserActivity"];

            // Binds the DataGrid
            grdUserActivity.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

.ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmPersonnel.aspx.cs"      Inherits="frmPersonnel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div align="center">

</div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="250px" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
    Width="300px">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Pay Rate:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Start Date:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="End Date:" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
        PostBackUrl="~/frmPersonnalVerified.aspx" Text="Submit" 
        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please paste the aspx code where you created grdUserActivity?

Comment: Would you be able to post the *.aspx as well?

Comment: Is your `grdUserActivity` within a templated control?

Comment: Out of blue, check for duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: This article should get you back up and running! http://www.ajaymatharu.com/the-name-does-not-exists-in-the-current-context-asp-net/

Comment: @Shai Cohen:  are you talking about: <asp:GridView ID="grdUserActivity" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: @Mike, we need the whole aspx. You might have inherited from a wrong class in it. Or put the grdUserActivity in a templated control, like Tim says.

Comment: ok so you have the runat="server" :) how about what @TimBJames asked? is it in a templated control?

Comment: @ShaiCohen:  I added the aspx code above.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so it is not in a templated control and the control exists in the designer file (from the answer below). Does the project build? If it does and the control is still not recognized, my only other idea is to recreate the page. Things get screwy sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a type-o

But your aspx file is pointing to `frmUserActivity` rather than `frmViewPersonnel`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmUserActivity.aspx.cs" Inherits="frmUserActivity" %>
```

So either you are editing the wrong `.cs` file, OR the wrong `.aspx` file ;)

**EDIT**

After seeing your edits, your `frmUserAcitivty` aspx page does not contain the `grdUserActivity` control. So of course it wont be found.