# Calling public method

Tags: c#

I thought that when your method is public you could invoke it from any class in your project...

```
namespace MethodTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Foo()
        {
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public static void asd(string[] args)
        {
            Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to invoke it from an other class I get an error

> Error CS0103  The name 'Foo' does not exist in the current
>   context   MethodTest  D:\Visual
>   Studio\MethodTest\MethodTest\Program.cs   23  Active
>   PS: And as I know if miss the access modifier it is private... Am I correct?

Comment: Try `Program.Foo();`

Comment: Did you try `Program.Foo();`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio saying name doesn't exist in current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062149/visual-studio-saying-name-doesnt-exist-in-current-context)

Comment: Looks like you should read some kind of beginner's book or tutorial about C#.

Comment: @UweKeim I am ... still this isn't specified there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a method from a different class like this.

Try the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void asd(string[] args)
    {
        Program.Foo();
    }
}
```

This way by using `Program.Foo();` you specify which exact method (from the different `Program` class) you want to use so that the CLR knows which method to invoke.

The reason why to call it like this is the `static` keyword in the declaration of the `Foo` method. Otherwise it would be called differently:

```
new Program().Foo();
```

Comment: what about the second part of my question, is the default access modifier private?(when I don't specify it in my program, example:`static void Foo()
        {

        }`)

Comment: The reason why to call it like this is the `static` keyword. Otherwise it would be called differently. The answer is incomplete

Comment: @ThomasWeller I agree with you. I will update my answer.