# the 'username' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a Login Page with ASP.Net using C#... and i have put my html code in **Login.aspx** page . that contains a textbox named username but when I give reference of my textbox in Login.aspx.cs to make the validations on this text box ... as

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Text))
{
...
...
}
```

i am getting an error that is saying ...-`"The 'username' doesn't exist in the current context"`...... 
how can i get rid of this error .... it is making me mas .... Help will be appreciable towards this error ... please help me ....

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %> 
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"> </asp:Content> 
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

Comment: Problem seems to be with you page directive have a look at that

Comment: You need to show more of your code if you want any help. Where would username be declared for example?

Comment: Please add your code of Login.aspx and Login.aspx.cs

Comment: Probably you missed the `runat="server"` attribute in your username textbox

Comment: Probably duplicate of this : [The name 'controlname' does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: the initial code in Login.aspx is

<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">..

Comment: @Will edit your question. if you want to put some code

Comment: @Will I added the code from your comment to your original question. If that is truly the markup you have, you have no `username` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you have taken.

If you have draged and droped ASP TextBox the automatically code has generated as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

which automatically contains `runat="server"`

But if you have taken HTML text box then code is as follows:

```
<input id="username" type="text" />
```

In this you will have to add the line on your own as `runat="server"`

It will look as follows:

```
<input id="username" type="text"  runat="server"/>
```

Then you can use it for serverside.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Thanx...... Buddy .... it really helped me .... Thankz a lot ..... I am just a Beginner with you .... again thanx a lot

Comment: @Will if answer is helpful, then you can accept this as a answer by ticking the checkbox.