# The name 'ProjectClient' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to create a visual webpart in a sandbox solution. i added a dropdownlist named ProjectClient in the ascx page and wrote a function to bind the dropdown in codebehind. but am getting this error as "The name 'ProjectClient' does not exist in the current context". I checked the ascx.g.cs page and the control id is correct there.  please help me to fix this.

ascx page:

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
                                        <asp:Label ID="pClient" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Client") %>' />
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectClient" runat="server" CssClass="ddclient" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
```

code behind file:

```
 public void BindDropDown()
        {
            ProjectClient.Items.Clear();
            if (listToBind != null)
            {
                ProjectClient.DataSource = listToBind;
                ProjectClient.DataTextField = textField;
                ProjectClient.DataValueField = valueField;
                ProjectClient.DataBind();
            }
           ProjectClient.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", ""));
        }
```

ascx.g.cs page:

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectExtensions.CodeGenerators.SharePointWebP" +
            "artCodeGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList @__BuildControl__control7() {
            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList @__ctrl;
            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList();
            @__ctrl.TemplateControl = this;
            @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this.Page);
            @__ctrl.ID = "ProjectClient";
            @__ctrl.CssClass = "ddclient";
            @__ctrl.Visible = false;
            return @__ctrl;
        }
```

Comment: Have you added `ProjectClient` namespace?

Comment: sorry i didn't get u.. where should i add it? can u explain it??

Comment: Ooh, it early, this comment makes no sense since `ProjectClient` is not a class :) Have you rebuilt you project?

Comment: yes. i did it many times. still not working

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context?rq=1