# C# Receive Data from Socket and put it in a String?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a socket server and am trying to receive a string from the client.

The client is perfect and when I use this

```
Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

byte[] b = new byte[100];
int k = s.Receive(b);
Console.WriteLine(k);
Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
}
```

All is okay and I get my string in the console.

But how can I get now my receive into a string so I can use it in a switch case?

Like this:

```
string action = Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
```

Error:

> The Name i isn't in the current context. 
>   its the only Error Message i get.

Comment: Please enhance your code example and show the definition of b and possibly s. Next, you certainly did not get the error you are describing because it clearly has typos in it. Please post a copy-pasted version of the exception plus the callstack, not a paraphrased write-up. I suspect you got the error described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: Okey i updated my Code Part a bit. I will check the Link :)

Comment: @Christoph I checked your link but not much helpfull or informing for me. 
I must say iam not often program with C#

Comment: You can't just say `Convert.ToChar(b[i])` and expect it to return a string in which the variable `i` looped through all the bytes of the `b`-array. Explicity create the loop variable `i` in a `for` statement, otherwise the variable won't exist. `string action = ""; for(int i=0; i < b.Length; i++) action += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);` would fill the `action` variable appropiatly.

Comment: _"The Name i isn't in the current context"_ - then you're not showing your actual code. Do you have a semicolon after the `for();`?

Comment: @CodeCaster No and i copy and pasted my exact code :) Please read the Answer below and my Comment to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `s` is a `Socket` object on which you call receive, you get an `byte[]` back. To convert this back to a string, use the appropiate encoding, e.g.

```
string szReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
```

Edit: Since the buffer `b` is always 100 bytes, but the actual number of bytes received varies with each connection, one should use the return value of the `Socket.Receive()` call to only convert the actual number of received bytes.

```
byte[] b = new byte[100];
int k = s.Receive(b);
string szReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b,0,k);
```

Comment: It works half Thanks ! :) 

But now it is showing correct when i write it in Console.... 
but My Switch Case will not work.. happend nothing :o 

 Console.WriteLine(szReceived);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

                switch (szReceived)
                {
                    case "ping":
                        Console.WriteLine("Ping wird ausgeführt!");
                        
                        break;
                    case "somethingelse":
                        
                        break;
                }

Comment: My first intuition says that you should cut off the array at the number of bytes you received. `Socket.Receive()` has a return value, and you need that to chop off your array at the actual bytes received. Use this:
`int k = s.Receive(b);
string szReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b.Take(k).ToArray());`
Then the string should be constructed perfectly. (You need a `using System.Linq;` for that, or use the second overload `string szReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b,0, k);`)

Comment: You did it ! :D
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 5):

This way no need set buffer size, it fits to response:

```
public static byte[] ReceiveAll(this Socket socket)
    {
        var buffer = new List<byte>();

        while (socket.Available > 0)
        {
            var currByte = new Byte[1];
            var byteCounter = socket.Receive(currByte, currByte.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            if (byteCounter.Equals(1))
            {
                buffer.Add(currByte[0]);
            }
        }

        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I think a minor optimization would be to put the currByte variable outside the while scope. Also, instead just taking a single byte at a time, you could take all the available. Nonetheless, a very robust solution!

Answer (score 4):

Init socket

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(m_ip);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, m_port);
```

Connect socket

```
socket.Connect(remoteEP);
```

Receive from socket

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int iRx = socket.Receive(buffer);
char[] chars = new char[iRx];

System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
System.String recv = new System.String(chars);
```

Send message

```
byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message");
socket.Send(byData);
```

Close socket

```
socket.Disconnect(false);
socket.Close();
```