# the name 'btnupdate' doesn't exist in current context in c#

Tags: c#

Here is my csfile:

```
protected void GridViewStudent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

             btnupdate.Visible = true;
         }
protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                OleDbConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
                con.Open();
                string SID = lblSID.Text;
                OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE registration set(username=@username,pwd=@pwd;address=@address,phone=@phone,email=@email,qualification=@qualification where SID=@SID", con);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Textpwd.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Textemail.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Textphone.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qualification", Textqualification.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("SID", SID);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                com.Dispose();
                ShowMessage("Student Data update Successfully......!");
                GridViewUser.EditIndex = -1;
                BindGridView();
                btnupdate.Visible = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowMessage(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="registrationuser.aspx.cs" Inherits="registration.registrationuser" %>

            <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" runat="server" Text="Update" visible="false" OnClick="btnupdate_Click"Height="30px" Width="75px" Font-Size="15px" ForeColor="#0094ff" BackColor="white" />
```

When i run the above code,it shows error like this,

> The name 'btnupdate' doesn't exist in current context

I m new to .net, please don't mind if any mistake in my code.

Can you please guide me to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Also have you checked once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: make sure you have a space here: `OnClick="btnupdate_Click"Height="30px"`

Comment: @devlincarnate: still stays same ....

Comment: The error occurs when you _run_ or when you _compile_?  Is that the _only_ error or are there others?

Comment: when i hit ctrl+shift+B....

Comment: @JonathanCarroll: I checked your link, in that the name 'btnupdate' doesn't exist in current context should same.. so my page also same..

Comment: Your "finally" doesn't make any sense to me, why create a new connection and then immediately close it (if its open, which its probably not)?

Comment: @RonBeyer: I just removed that code, and still stays same issue..

Comment: @Rani I wasn't suggesting it had anything to do with your problem, I was just noting my confusion over what you were trying to accomplish there.

Comment: @Rani Is your button inside an `asp:Content` control, like this?`<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">...</asp:Content>`

Comment: @rlb.usa: yes.. inside the content only..

Comment: @Rani Just try it... stop running website (if it running), change the update button id i.e ) btnUpdate to anything. **Save the changes**. then undo the change. Again  **Save the changes**. hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look on your .ascx.designer.cs and tell us if has an btnupdate there?

I suggest you to delete this object and recreate it.

Comment: No, btnupdate  not in .ascx.designer.cs.. may i know, how to recreate.?

Comment: Just delete the current one from your page, save and then create another one with the same name, if don't work, change the name too haha.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" runat="server" Text="Update" visible="false" OnClick="btnupdate_Click"Height="30px" Width="75px" Font-Size="15px" ForeColor="#0094ff" BackColor="white" />

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the control isn't appearing in your designer file. Are you using Visual Studio, and is this an ASP.NET Web Application?

If so, then you can try this:

In the solution explorer you can right click on the project that contains the affected file and select '**Convert to Web Application**'.  This will force Visual Studio to recreate all of the designer files in the project.

Do note that depending on your configuration, the conversion will change the **CodeFile** property that points to the .cs file to be a **Codebehind** property at the top of your .ascx page.  In my experience, I've had to change this back to being **CodeFile** in order to get my project to run correctly.

I've done several searches into this kind of error, but I haven't been able to figure out why the designer files sometimes don't update when saving changes made to the .ascx file.