# Error The name 'Identifier' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have C# enumeration

```
public enum Item
{
    Identifier = 0,
    Title = 1,
    StartOfMedia = 2,
    Duration = 3,
    Content = 4,
    EOM = 5,
    FirstAirDate = 6,
    BoxId = 7,
    Seg = 8,
}
```

And JavaScript code where enumeration is used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateFieldStatus() {}
    var Identifier = "";
    Identifier = @Item.Identifier.ToString();
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Configuration").validate({
                rules: {
                    "config.Format["@Identifier"].StartPos":
            {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                range: [1, 200]
            }, },
            }); 
    });
</script>
```

But I have Error:

> "The name 'Identifier' does not exist in the current context"

What I do wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: In which file your ` @Item.Identifier.ToString();` is written?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  "config.Format["+Identifier+"].StartPos":
```