# Asp.Net Newly added Controls are not being recognized in .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on Asp.Net application. Everything was working fine until when I copy pasted couple of labels on a page and tried to set text to them on server file (.cs), they were showing in intellisense but when I compiled error showed `'The name 'lbltest' does not exist in the current context'`. What could be the issue?

Comment: The .designer.cs file can sometimes get messed up when copying and pasting controls... where you have pasted them, try something like saving the page, then edit the control, i.e. delete the close tag, save it, add the close tag save it etc etc

Comment: I tried many , but nothing works. actually I think that there some error in the code which not showing , how can I get to that error if it exist?

Comment: Have a quick look in the designer file to see if the newly added controls are there.... Run the application in debug mode, if that doesn't lead you to the issue then try the good old process of elimination; add one control at a time and test it.

Comment: Your issue is nothing new, lots of people over the last 8 years have experienced it... Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context/1981228#1981228

Comment: My old controls are working fine. Error is only occuring with the newly added controls