# Name does not exist in current context error

Tags: c#, xna

I'm using the tutorial *Introduction to Programming Through Game Development Using Microsoft XNA Game Studio*. I'm having trouble in the section about adding resources to a project.

I copied the instructions fairly well from what I can tell, except for changing the name of the picture - Still I get 3 errors being screen saying various names don't exist in the current context. How can I resolve these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Firstly, do not post screen shots, always provide code with question in proper format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name 'controlname' does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your texture and your rectangle are defined, initialized and disposed in your Init-Method. They are not accessible outside of that method. What you have to do is either pass them as method-parameters (not possible in in the Drawing-Method of XNA) or to make them "more public" and define them outside of your Init-Method:

```
private Texture2D starPic600Texture;
private Rectangle starPic600Rect;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    starPic600Rect = new Rectangle(30,20,600,600);
    starPic600Texture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("starPic600");
}
```

PS: Next time add your code-samples to your Question as `code` instead of Pictures. This would make it a Little bit easier to copy-paste and addapt your samples.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, that had been driving me up the wall! thanks for the help, and ill definitely keep that in mind for the future.