# 'MasterPage' does not contain a definition for

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, master-pages

I'm wondering all the possible reasons i might get a errors like:

**'MasterPage' does not contain a definition for ...**

or

**The name '...' does not exist in the current context**

I know that these errors are *NOT* code related. This is a new project that i just pulled from source control. My colleagues are running perfectly fine with this same code which leads me to believe the issue is locally with my dev environment. I thought it might be a file permission issue and so i reset the file permissions on the entire solution which did not resolve the issue.

What am i missing? Why are my ASPX pages throwing these errors at me?

Any ideas on where to look next to resolve this would be awesome.

TIA

> **UPDATE:**
>
> I managed to resolve all the errors i was seeing by actually running
>   the solution (despite the Visual Studio errors i was getting). Once i
>   stopped and came out of debug mode, the errors were gone in Visual
>   Studio.
>
> I would very much like to know what is happening with VS that after
>   running the solution the errors resolve?!?! Is VS creating some sort
>   of reference behind the scenes?
>
> Very confused....

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context]

Comment: That's not my issue, everything is matching and like i said this code is working in other environments, so it can't be code related, nor do i want to modify working code.

Comment: I resolved the initial error and updated my question above...

Comment: Sometimes VS gets a little confused. Restarting it will help most of the time (unless the error are actually genuine of course).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code behind file. If you aspx page has something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AdminMaster.master.cs" Inherits="admin_AdminMaster" %>
```

(admin being the sub-folder name), then code behind should look like:

```
public partial class admin_AdminMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```