# Why is element I declared in XAML unreachable from C# code?

Tags: c#, xamarin

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WacyN.png)

I declare ListView in XAML (MainPage.xaml):

```
<ListView x:Name="ShoppingListsLV"
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
              Margin="3"/>
```

And tried to access it from my code (MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
ShoppingListsLV.ItemsSource = new string[] { "test", "test 2"};
```

And I have an error:

> CS0103: The name ShoppingListsLV does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sometimes it happens, don't know the actual route cause, try *re-open VS* and *create new control*

Comment: Check also here-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are writing your code after the call:

`InitializeComponent();`

Also, check that your view is referencing the right code-behind file:

`<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="YourNamespace.MainPage">`

Finally, try to close VS, then go and delete from your projects folders the following ones:

Android - bin

Android - obj

iOS - bin

iOS - obj

This action will clear completely your cache.
After this is done, reopen your solution in VS and perform a clear, re-build operation. Your references should be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the page Custom Tool property to MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml where your list exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, if you see the errors you need to build the app, it should work and you won't see the error anymore.