# Why is compiler not recognizing my controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have an aspx page that my colleague designed for me to stick on the back end.  I made a few alterations to the page, adding various controls and things - and now the compiler doesn't recognize any of the controls on the page!  The Intellisense is working just fine - I can type `txtName.` and as I push the `.` all the properties of a TextBox pop up as normal... but when I try compile, the compiler says "Name 'txtName' is not declared".

There's obviously a secret switch somewhere.  Any ideas what it might be?

**EDIT:** I just realized the difference between this form and every other form in the project: **there's no .aspx.designer.vb file**.  Any idea how to force generation of this file?

Comment: Are all of your controls VS controls?  Or you have also third part controls?

Comment: There may be some 3rd party controls - but even the standard VS controls are causing compiler errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer!
The .aspx.designer.vb file was missing.
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-fi/45334#45334) is how to get it back.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem and it came down to the namespace declaration for the code behind file in the ASPX file

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="AdminConsoleAudit.aspx.vb" Inherits="AdminConsoleAudit" Title="Untitled Page"
    StylesheetTheme="cs" Strict="true" %>
```

This has to change to a

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="<namespaceHere>.AdminConsoleAudit.aspx.vb" Inherits="AdminConsoleAudit" Title="Untitled Page"
    StylesheetTheme="cs" Strict="true" %>
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you!  It was the namespace!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it cannot find the code behind file.

It may be that you have a hardcode path somewhere, if you have the code in a different directory than you colleague, then you could get this problem.

If this is what is causing the problem then there are 2 ways to fix it:

- place all code in same directory structure
- use relative paths

It could also be that you have not copied all the required files. Try searching for txtName in your code.

Comment: Nope, everything is in one folder.

Comment: Are you able to find the file that defines txtName?