# The name 'txtinput1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

First off , I know the question looks very similar to the question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316757/cant-access-control-id-in-code-behind)

But somehow the fixes suggested there arent working for me. So here goes.
I have the following code 
in my aspx page :

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtinput1" runat="server" Width="200px" 
       ontextchanged="txtinput1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

But when I try the following code in my code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StemService.ServiceClient myClient = new StemService.ServiceClient();
            string input = txtinput1.Text;
        }
```

I get the error saying that 'txtinput1' does not exist in the context.
For sake of completion here's my default.aspx https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5217410.

P.S. Im a C# **noob**, so I may be missing something obvious.

EDIT: Designer.cs https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5217484

EDIT 2: Default.aspx.cs: https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5217517

Comment: Check the designer.cs file to see if it has been added...

Comment: Please check the edit. It seems to be present in it.

Comment: Can you add the .cs file as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your designer.cs seems lacking of the proper declaration of the namespace

```
 namespace Project3_ConsumptionApplication
 {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the code doesnt seem to show any compile time errors but Intellisense still doesnt seem to detect the field, is this normal ? or will there be problems later?

Comment: when I add the namespace the error disappears. I dont know for sure whether it will run properly though. Here's the modified designer (you may double check)https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5217607

Comment: So the error is solved, 'the program runs properly' is another matter :-)