# Fixing "name does not exist in the current context" errors in Web Developer Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, vwdexpress

The name lblorder does not exist in the current context label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblorder" runat="server" Text="Ordernumber: "></asp:Label>
```

code behind

```
string test = lblorder.Text;
```

I **hate** this error.
Once in a while it just pops up and I know that it has something to do with deleting the aspx.designer.cs and rebuilding the page or solution file but I work in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition and I dont have this aspx.designer.cs file

..help me..

Answer (score 1):

You could always open the visual studio solution and add the xml for the file.

```
<Compile Include="blahblah\blahblah.ascx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>blahblah.ascx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete the aspx.designer.cs you should be able to right click on the .aspx file and click "Convert to Web Application". This will regenerate you aspx.designer.cs file.

Comment: hipplar, the question pointed out that this cannot be done in VWD Express

Comment: Although this answer suggests it can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008588/label-doesnt-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: I've tried to delete the files (aspx + aspx.cs) and created new ones with the same filename but I still have the problem, and also with new filenames after deleting the original, it doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried "Cleaning" the solution? Right click the solution file, click "Clean Solution", then rebuild.

Comment: I created a webapplication of the website solution , so now I have aspx.designer.cs files and can clean the solution and convert it to a webapplication, but the error still exists .. :/

Comment: I just added the missing line in the designer file, now it works ; protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblorder;

Comment: but this is not a perminent solution; the changes are deleted after every built .... could anybody help me please...!

Answer (score 0):

I created a webapplication of the website solution , so now I have aspx.designer.cs files and can clean the solution and convert it to a webapplication, but the error still exists .. 
So I just added the missing line in the designer file, now it works ; protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblorder; 
 but this is not a perminent solution; the changes are deleted after every built .... 
and then she found it that you have to use a findcontrol when labels etc are placed in a **nested repeater**

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem but I fixed it by providing the directive in the aspx file (html file)

The above format and content can be obtained by making a new web application project and copything the above similar directive that is automatically generated by visual studio!!