# How to Inherits a file placed INSIDE a project folder (except the Default.aspx) in VisualStudio2013?

Tags: inheritance, syntax

I have this line for the Default.aspx file:

> Page Title="Home" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
> AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
> Inherits="MYPROJECTWEB._Default"

and the source (behind) code seems to recognise the specified .aspx file without throwing exceptions.

How is the correct syntax in the case I have to specify a file inside a folder in the project (in this case 'Occasions.aspx.cs')?
The following seem not to work ((:

> Page Title="Occasioni" Language="C#"
> MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
> CodeBehind="Occasions.aspx.cs"
> Inherits="MYPROJECTWEB.Application_Occasions"
>
> Page Title="Occasioni" Language="C#"
> MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
> CodeBehind="Occasions.aspx.cs"
> Inherits="MYPROJECTWEB_Application_Occasions"

What is the subtle trick? ))
Thanks

Comment: The "<%@" symbols are deliberately missing (for display conflicts in the present post)

Comment: I mean something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008588/label-doesnt-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: It should be like `Inherits="Foldername_pagename"`