# Visual Studio 2013 has stopped updating aspx.designer.cs files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a large-ish web forms application and VS has stopped updating .aspx.designer.cs files in the last few days.

It seemed like the designer updates initially became flaky (sometimes update, sometimes not) then stopped updating altogether.  Now I have to manually edit the designer file after adding a control to a page before I can compile.

I've searched and tried all the suggestions like switching from markup to design view and back etc - no change. The only thing that kind of works is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334/5331772) but even then the generated designer file often doesn't contain references to all the controls on the page.  And also that only works on a per-file basis.  Ideally I would like the whole project to update/generate designer files correctly again.

I've tried cleaning the solution - no change.

VS details:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
- Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00079
- Installed Version: Professional

Any suggestions appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not running the application/site while adding controls. I've noticed that VS will lock the designer files while in debug mode and doesn't sync up when you exit debug mode.

Also, your link is broken, doesn't point to anything so I can't see what you were referencing to.

Comment: Definitely not running/debugging and the designer files not updating - thanks anyway.  Link fixed.

Comment: @Danzig maybe this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6508420/1034308): 

Close Visual Studio, then delete Temporary ASP.NET Files from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\Your_.Net_Version\ProjectName` 

Delete the folder `ProjectName` and re-start Visual Studio. 

If you use IIS, you may need to stop the server/site to be able to delete the temp files.

Answer (score 0):

I think what caused this was a somewhat flaky local install of the project from TFS.  It compiled but still had red squiggly lines under a few namespaces at design time.  Once the project references were all clean the designer files were also updating correctly.