# New pages added to VS2017 don't link to their respective codebehind and designer pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Any new page I add to VS2017 is not linking with its respective codebehind or designer pages:

- Happens across all my projects and solutions
- Right clicking aspx code does not show "View code" in context menu    (works in existing pages)
- Right clicking .aspx in solution explorer shows "View code" option and opens code behind as expected
- Controls are not automatically added for reference in designer and navigation menu (changed autoeventwireup)
- Intellisense in page declaration only shows 1 option ("db"), where normally it should show 15 or 20 options - new and existing pages
- Compiles OK
- I can add the reference directly to the deisgner page and am able to reference it in the codebehind
- EDIT: Also the intellisense for all controls just says "db" too

This is not a problem in VS2015. I have both installed and have opened a solution in 2015 and the above problems don't exist.

Comment: Is "Lightweight Solution Load" on or off?

Right click your SLN in VS2017 if you are unsure.

Comment: No the option to "Enable lightweight solution load" is available

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to clear out my temporary ASP.net files, as per Kenan Deen's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508252/designer-cs-not-updating-when-new-controls-added-to-aspx):