# .aspx codefile page unable to recognise control on the page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, code-behind

I am getting a compilation error on a website.  There is a repeater declared in the aspx file as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs"
        Inherits="MyClass" %>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
…
```

And the class is defined as follows:

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptMyRepeater.DataSource = GetMyDataSource();
            rptMyRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that rptMyRepeater is not recognised.  Note that I copied these files in from another project, and so don't have a designer.cs file.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-fi) question which implies a "Convert to Web Application" would fix the problem.  As I'm referencing a CodeFile rather than a CodeBehind, does this apply, or is there a better way?  Is a designer file even necessary in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-fi/45334#45334

Comment: This is the link that I posted myself in the question.  I don't believe that it answers my question though

Comment: The repeater should be contained in a form.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are saying is you don't have just the *contents* of designer.cs, add this to designer.cs:
`protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater rptMyRepeater;`
If you do not have a designer.cs file at all, add it to aspx.cs -i.e codefile- and it should work.

Simply this is the equivalent of what the designer file supposed to be doing, controls are not much different than class variables as I see.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could check:

- Ensure that your .cs file is set to **Compile** in the properties
- Try using CodeBehind instead of CodeFile
- If your page class is inside a namespace then ensure it is fully qualified in the aspx file
- If you are using a Web Application Project then right-click and **Convert to Web Application**