# How to create designer code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an ascx that when I drag/drop any control, nothing is created in the designer and I don't have any intellisense in code behind.  Are there steps for manually creating the designer and initialization code?  Or some other approach?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: have you checked this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-f

Answer (score 1):

Right click your `ascx` or `aspx` file in solution explorer and click `Covert to Web Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the designer file, close the ascx and re-open it.  VS should recreate the designer.

Comment: Did it - still nothing for it in the designer file.