# Visual Studio 2013 designer not generating code for Telerik controls

Tags: asp.net, tfs, telerik, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a web project that uses Telerik controls. The project was originally created using Visual Studio 2010, and underwent the upgrade to 2012 before I got there.

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 and for some reason VS2013 doesn't recognize Telerik controls as part of the auto-generation of the designer file.

For example if I added a control to the .aspx page:
`<telerik:RadButton ID="rbn1" runat="server"></telerik:RadButton>`

The designer.vb file should be auto-generated to contain:
`Protected WithEvents rbn1 As Global.Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton`

However the designer never auto-adds Telerik controls. Asp and user-defined controls are added as expected. Additionally, my coworkers are using VS2012 and the designer generates correctly, so I don't think it's an issue with Telerik.

We're using the latest version of the Telerik.dll files (2013.3.1114.40). Additionally, I have got it working by removing and re-adding the Telerik.dll references, but it only works until I restart Visual Studio.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054823/visual-studio-not-connecting-designer-to-code-behind) appears to be a similar issue to mine, however Telerik does officially support VS2013. I have also reached out to Telerik directly for support on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Telerik support they determined that the issue was with Team Foundation Server and the Visual Studio option to "Get everything when a solution or project is opened". Disabling that appears to solve the issue.