# Visual Studio 2012 cannot resolve symbol or Errors control is not a member of class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012
Web Site Project > Site works perfectly fine and using IIS and attaching to IIS to debug code.

However, if I try to build the site inside of Visual Studio I am getting lots of Errors  ‘pnlName’ is not a member of ‘Page_Name’
In the code behind I am getting errors ‘Cannot resolve symbol ‘pnlName’

.ascx Page

```
<li style="margin-right:0;" id="pnlName" runat="server"><a href="/cart" title="Checkout" class="global-checkout">Checkout</a></li>
```

.ascx.vb page

```
Me.pnlName.Attributes.Remove("style")
```

I have cleaned, rebuild and nothing gets rid of these errors, but again the site works as designed, but I would like to launch and debug inside of Visual Studio.

More Details ---
What I am stating is this is a solution using the Web Site Project instead of a Web Application Project.

Web Site projects do not require Designer.vb files, Web Application Projects add Designer.vb files in the solution.

A Web Site project does not compile the code, but simply uses the .vb files and they have to be migrated to the server with the .aspx files. The following link provides all the details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Currently the only way I can debug this Solution is to attach to the w3wp.exe process running locally on my work station.

The Solution is comprised of two Web Sites, which I cannot get it to compile because of the following errors -  'webServerControlName' is not a member of '(Protected Code Behind Class Name)'  I posted to Stack Overflow to see if anyone has experienced this issue with MS Visual Studio Web Site Projects.

Comment: Perhaps the designer file has lost the control.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-f) and its answers to see if that helps.

Comment: This is a Web site project.  The project does not contain Designer.vb files.