# ASP.Net Change reference from GAC to File

Tags: asp.net

[image: My Web site Rference pages]

I need to do two things...

1. Change the reference from GAC to file. As you can see, I don't have a References Folder.
2. There is only a Debug build. How do I create a Release build and publish that.

Why is this project so different to any other web site I have created?

Comment: This is a web site and not a web application, that is why it's different. I recommend creating a ***web application -project*** instead.

Comment: [This is the answer thanks to the tip from @esko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-f)